# GCC 4.7.0 can't link to SDLmain and SDL

Tags: c++, gcc, sdl

I tried configuring CodeBlocks( with gcc 4.4.1 ) to use SDL using Lazy Foos' tutorial and it worked fine, everything compiled, linked etc. 
The problem occurred when I changed the compiler to 4.7.0.
Using the EXACT same settings I get:

```
ld.exe  cannot find -lSDLmain
ld.exe  cannot find -lSDL
```

How can I make this work?

PS: tried linking the libraries using a full path ( didn't work )

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to specify ld where to find the libraries using -Lpath_to_your_library.

Just like when telling gcc where to find the header files using -Iyour_path_to_your_headers.

Comment: if you're referring to Search directories->Linker, I did specify the correct folder

Comment: Well, see if `libSDL.la` and `libSDLmain.a` are there.

Comment: @jrok of course they are there, how else would it work with 4.4.1 ?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't say it still works with old version and you said you've got the dirs set up correctly.